# react native router flux is not push single screen multiple time

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native-router-flux for navigate between screen.
it is working proper for open another screen.

> I want to open same screen multiple time

In My code **ProductListScreen** and **ProductScreen** available.
I'm going **ProductListScreen** to **ProductScreen** it's working.
then after open **ProductScreen** from **ProductScreen** it's not working.

> How to open (Push) **ProductScreen** from **ProductScreen**

My Code:-

**Router.js**

```
return <Router>
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene  key="ProductListScreen"
    component={ProductListScreen} initial = {true}/>
    <Scene  key="ProductScreen"
    component={ProductScreen} hideNavBar={false}/>
  </Scene>
</Router>;
```

**ProductListScreen.js**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> Actions.ProductScreen()}>
  <Text>View Product Detail</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**ProductScreen.js**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> Actions.ProductScreen()}>
  <Text>View Related Product Detail</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785699/react-native-router-flux-transition-and-history-using-this-same-scene-but-with/51791573#51791573) , maybe can help you

Comment: It's not working